# webapp2.Route can't find static_dir files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

### app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
- url: /.*
  script: myapp.application
```

### myapp.py

```
class DeleteRecord(BaseHandler):
  def get(self, record_id):
    # do something

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/home', HomePage),
  ('/error_message', ErrorMessage),
  webapp2.Route(r'/delete_record/<record_id>', DeleteRecord),
  ('/sign_out', SignOut),
```

When "/delete_record/record_id" is called, the code executes well, but it can't read files kept under "/stylesheets"  (=broken css images on webpage).

What would need to be fixed? Thanks :)

Comment: can you provide us with the html fragment where you refer to the stylesheets?

Comment: Like I mentioned below Daniel's comment, the "/delete_record/" assumes all css files under it, i.e. "/delete_record/stylesheets/image.png" etc. while my main application is on same level as "/stylesheets" directly.  It appears that with my webapp2Routing, static files one level up is not readable..

Comment: i'm sorry, i have no idea what you are even trying to say. why would you assume the style sheets are under /delete_record when you know they are not??? it sounds like you just found the bug...

Comment: Yes that's right. Probably in my Jinja2 template <img src="stylesheets/image.png">  should rather be written "clearly" to be  <img src="http://www.example.com/stylesheets/image.png">               However I was just hoping that "/" in jinja2 refers to top level, irrespective of if I call from /delete_record or /home.

Comment: there is absolutely no need for <img src="example.com/stylesheets/image.png">. You need exaclty <img src="/stylesheets/image.png">. Note the "/" before stylesheets.

Comment: And also you are confusing the server side and the client side. The url is accessed by the client. **jinja2 has nothing to do with it, and neither does webapp2.Route**

Comment: Great. Thanks. Works well. Yes I am kind of new to webapp2,python,gae...I started from "Hello World" example to build a new cms :)